# Does my toilet have a manufacturing defect?

Tags: toilet

I purchased a Kohler toilet about 6 months ago for my bath remodel. I finally got the bath finished after a sequence of delays. The toilet is about 1/8" off level in the rear (see photo) and rocks significantly. BTW, this was not a cheap toilet so I'm a bit miffed. Before I try to exchanged it, I wanted to check if it's reasonable to do so. I know I can shim it but I feel like this is a manufacturing defect that shouldn't have left the factory. It's a Kohler Cimarron from HD.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure its the toilet and not your floor that's the problem?

Comment: We need a better picture, we need to see what the level is like on the floor, and a pic with toilet off would be good.  There are some bunky toilets but uneveness is usually the flooring/plumbing.

Comment: If the toilet were on a firm level base and the rim were off 1/8" in the rear, I could see it being by design from Kohler. But wobbles? Unless you can clearly show how the toilet configuration causes the wobble, I have to believe the problem is in the installation, not the toilet. Your picture does not demonstrate anything meaningful to me.

Comment: Is the toilet installed in that picture?  It looks like it's simply sitting on a carpeted floor, in which case I wouldn't expect the toilet to **not** sit flat.  The drain on the toilet sits slightly lower than the bottom of the toilet, this allows the drain on the toilet to sit down inside the floor drain (which should be level with or just above the floor).

Comment: Unlikely to be the toilet, they are made in a mould.

Comment: They're fired and can deform quite a bit during the kiln process. I've picked up rejects cheap.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to show with your picture, but nothing definitive can be said based on the picture.

Comment: The question should be closed unless we get more info from person with problem.

Comment: Look at it this way: in 10 years all toilets will be made out of plastic.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread but in case more people come across it I have added this post.

I have a brand new Kohler Ciimarron elongated bowl toilet that I installed and had the same issue with wobble. I pulled the toilet and used a straight edge just as you did in the photo. It has the same issue of the small support ribs are taller than the outside rim by  strong 1/8”. The casting is defective. Yes they are made in a mold but there is the opportunity for defects even then . poor quality control on Kohler’s end. I am returning it right now. I will try a different brand. My guess is that they are all manufactured overseas which adds to the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The toilet is upside down in this photo and level is resting on the bottom, across the drain -- admittedly this is not the best photo. The original idea of the photo is to show the gap between level and bottom of toilet. The level is only being used as something straight, not level as in horizontal. In this photo the level is resting on the bottom of the toilet. The problem is the level rocks on the supports and edge/rim of the bottom -- in other words they are not aligned and off by 1/8". I have another Kohler, same model and it's within 1/32 so I think I answered my own question that this toiled it defective.

Comment: The drain horn on some toilets are intentionally slightly lower than the fixture bottom. It fits into the bevel of the toilet flange so does not prevent the toilet from bearing flat on the floor. Some variance in manufacture is not necessarily a defect. What is an issue is if the toilet does not fully bear on the floor when installed.

Comment: Yes, the drain horn is lower but it isn't the issue -- it's the supports around the horn, they are not level with the base, although they should be. The level doesn't touch the drain horn

Comment: OK, I still wasn't getting it, sorry. It's hard to grasp the whole picture from just a detail image. Yes, there should be nothing protruding below the support rim other than the drain horn. Perhaps the base was inadvertently distorted when it was removed from the mold.

Answer (score 0):

I think the toilet is defective. I have a similar problem of a toilet wobbling front and back. I found that the inside 
ribs at the bottom of a toilet protruding over the base of a toilet. I am going to try to replace it today. I was looking to find information about this problem, but your question is the only one I found. No one wants to talk about this problem much. People are just using different methods to make the toilet stable not realising that the toilet itself could be defective.

Answer (score 0):

I beleive I have a defective toilet as well. American standard I think. 9 months ago I installed it with a wax ring. It seemed sturdy after the install. over time i notice a slight wobble when I would sit on it. over several months the wobble got worse and I noticed  small leak. I suspect after the wax settled the ribs on the bottom started to meet the floor. by eyeball its easy to see the ribs protrude beyond the outer rim at the base causing the unevenness. my plan is to use a grinder to shorten the ribs that stick out beyond the outer base. it wobbles when put on level concrete. I think it's too late to return it and it seems like an easy fix if i can grind off the parts that extend beyond the outer rim. If i can fix the wobble sitting on flat concrete I'm confident it will be flat in my bathroom. I will try the fix tomorrow and report back here. BoB

Comment: how does that answer the question?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/138412)